# Add one div at a time, or delete duplicates fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a part of a project I'm working on in which I have to add repeated instances of the same div.  It mostly works, however, instead of adding individual instances, the previous div added seems to be repeating itself, rather than having the "original div" adding.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3xazjak/8/) together with the code I'm using so far:

```
 <div class="shape" id="plan4_shape">
         <span class="bakkant">
         <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4width" value="w1"/>
         <span class="times"> &times;</span>
         <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4length" value="l1" />
         </span>
          <script id="template" type="text/template">
             <span class="bakkant" id="bakkant">
             <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4width" value="w"/>
             <span class="times"> &times;</span>
             <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm" name="p4length" value="l" />
             <button class="close" id="close">&times;</button>
             </span>
            </script>
            <button type="button" name="add_row" class="addrow" id="addrow4" onClick="addrow()">Add row</button>
            <textarea name="more_info" id="profiles" placeholder="Beskriv fritt, vilka kanter du vill få profilerade."></textarea>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#addrow4').click(function() {
    var $clone = $($('#template').html());
    $clone.attr('id', "bakkant" + ++i);
     $clone.find('p').attr("Bob" + ++i)
    $clone.find('input').attr('value', "l" + ++i);
    $clone.find('input').attr('value', "w" + ++i);
    $('.bakkant').append($clone);
  });

  $('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: avoid doing cloning `html`. generate html on click add more.

Comment: Can you give me more details?  I'm assuming you need to put the html as a variable in the jquery and then add that each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to add the new row at the last, you need to do

```
 $('.bakkant').last().append($clone);
```

You need not do `++i` for changing every id or value attribute, just increment it once for each event.

Working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j3xazjak/10/).

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll just replace value with name, and it's perfect.  :)